# Sorting really large table from CSV files

Tags: python, r, csv, sorting

I have around 100 millions line of row from a table. The table has several columns, but th emost important columns are 3. Let's say column `colA`, `colB`, and `colC`.

I want to sort `colC` values grouped by `colA` and `colB`.

So, for example:

```
colA    colB    colC
A       B       1
C       A       3
C       B       1
B       C       5
A       B       2
C       B       8
```

I want the result to be:

```
colA    colB    colC
A       B       1
A       B       2
B       C       5
C       A       3
C       B       1
C       B       8
```

Imagine there are around 10,000 of `colA` values and 2000 of `colB` values and total number of rows can reach 100,000,000 rows.

How can I sort this with R or python efficiently?

Additional info:

My PC has 10 cores and 62 GB usable RAM.

Comment: How many columns (and do you care about them)?

Comment: There are 10 columns but only 3 that are matters.

Comment: If your data can fit nto the RAM use the fread function of data.table package. Then use the sorting in data.table. I will post the full code later.

Comment: So the missing column values are represented by null?

Comment: Have you tried pandas for python?

Comment: I have tried python, both pandas and read line by line and manually sort it. Both takes a lot of times due to only use 1 core.

Comment: there are no missing values in my table. There are many columns, but other than 3, it is just information.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple in `data.table`:

```
fread("csv-file.csv", select = c("colA", "colB", "colC"), key = c("colA", "colB", "colC"))
```

As of February 2018, the development version of `fread` is much faster than the stable version: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation